# Express js, what could cause an object to be sent through to a view as the literal word 'object'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using nodejs, express and ejs.

I have the variable 'result' defined that when I read out using console.log(result) from within the router.get function on my index page produces a perfectly formed array of objects.

I then proceed to render the new page within the router.get function:

```
res.render('new_page', { title: 'New Page Header', parameters : result.rows});
```

The title appears correctly on the new page, but as for the parameters, when I directly reference them in the ejs file (<%=parameters%>) they appear as below:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

There are correctly seven rows, but they appear with the literal word object in as opposed to the actual content. Likewise when I reference a single row within the ejs, it will appear as [object Object], and if I try to delve within the rows nothing appears.

What are the possible causes for an object being passed as the literal 'object'?  Could easily be something simple as I am a novice but for the life of me I can't work it out.

Comment: How do you want it to render?.   If you want it in JSON format then you could just do -> `parameters : JSON.stringify(result.rows)`, otherwise you need to expand your EJS to traverse the array.

Comment: That's what an arrays toString looks like, iirc.

Comment: It's not the literal word `object`, it's the string `"[object Object]"`. That's what you get from `toString` on an object that doesn't override `toString`. From your output, it looks like you have an array of objects and you're using `toString` on it, which will use `toString` on each element of the array and join them together with `,`.

Comment: You can't directly render an array in your template.  You have to iterate the array in your template language and render values from the array.  You also can't render an object, you have to render a property of that object that has a string value (or a value that is easily converted to a string).

Answer (score 0):

The object gets stringified when you render it with ejs. What happens under the hood is the `toString()` method is being called. You can see this yourself if you do something like

```
console.log({key:"value"}.toString())
```

If you want to see the actual content of the array of objects you need to call `JSON.stringify(result.rows)` That will pass a "string" to res.render and not an  "object".